# How to generate a stacked geom_area(fill) with data in separate columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following data frame **df**, which has an X column and 3 related value columns (Y1..Y3), and additional columns not used in this graph.

My question: **How/Can I use the data from *df* to create a geom_area(fill) plot?**

All examples I can find only apply if I create another data frame with the data in separate rows, like in **df2**.  Simplified data is given below.

```
head(df, 3)
  nth    tot     y1     y2     y3 other1 other2
1   1 1.9449 0.8724 0.1070 0.9655     31     63
2   2 1.2693 0.4519 0.5235 0.2939     46     67
3   3 2.6845 0.8147 0.8963 0.9735     46     42

head(df2,3)
  nth tag    val
1   1  y1 0.8724
2   2  y1 0.4519
3   3  y1 0.8147
```

If the answer is that reformatting to **df2** is required, what is the "best" way to create **df2**?

```
df <- structure(list(x = 1:15, tot = c(1.9449, 1.2693, 2.6845, 1.3311, 1.0887, 1.7291, 1.8173, 1.6097, 1.9690, 1.4961, 1.5411, 1.5308, 1.5634, 1.3179, 1.1292), y1 = c(0.8724, 0.4519, 0.8147, 0.9769, 0.3094, 0.0342, 0.8947, 0.9457, 0.9295, 0.5742, 0.2235, 0.2140, 0.0472, 0.8690, 0.2460), y2 = c(0.1070, 0.5235, 0.8963, 0.0852, 0.0193, 0.8287, 0.7999, 0.5966, 0.4534, 0.8592, 0.3610, 0.9233, 0.7566, 0.1929, 0.5331), y3 = c(0.9655, 0.2939, 0.9735, 0.2690, 0.7600, 0.8662, 0.1227, 0.0674, 0.5861, 0.0627, 0.9566, 0.3935, 0.7596, 0.2560, 0.3501), other1 = c(31, 46, 46, 41, 32, 22, 49, 35, 41, 27, 37, 26, 20, 44, 30), other2 = c(63, 67, 42, 55, 73, 30, 75, 76, 53, 38, 69, 52, 30, 78, 63)), .Names = c("x", "tot", "y1", "y2", "y3", "other1", "other2"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame") 
df2 <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L), tag = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("y1", "y2", "y3"), class = "factor"), val = c(0.8724, 0.4519, 0.8147, 0.9769, 0.3094, 0.0342, 0.8947, 0.9457, 0.9295, 0.5742, 0.2235, 0.2140, 0.0472, 0.8690, 0.2460, 0.1070, 0.5235, 0.8963, 0.0852, 0.0193, 0.8287, 0.7999, 0.5966, 0.4534, 0.8592, 0.3610, 0.9233, 0.7566, 0.1929, 0.5331, 0.9655, 0.2939, 0.9735, 0.2690, 0.7600, 0.8662, 0.1227, 0.0674, 0.5861, 0.0627, 0.9566, 0.3935, 0.7596, 0.2560, 0.3501)), .Names = c("x", "tag", "val"), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(x, val, color=tag, fill=tag)) + geom_area(position='fill')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic way to produce `df2` from `df` is using `melt(...)` in the `reshape2` package.

```
library(reshape2)
df3 <- melt(df,id.vars="x",measure.vars=c("y1","y2","y3"))
ggplot(df3, aes(x, value, color=variable, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_area(position='fill')
```

[image]

So `melt(...)` takes a data frame in "wide" format (data in different columns) and converts it to "long" format (data in 1 column, with original column names in a separate column). You identify the columns which are repeated using `id.vars=...`, and the columns containing the data in `measure.vars=....`. Then, `melt(...)` produces a new data frame with the repeating columns, the data in a column `value` and the column names in a column `variable`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps - but you didn't directly answer the question about using **df** directly; is it not possible?

Comment: AFAIK not with `position="fill"`.

Comment: Weird, but kinda what I expected.